# ip route save binary or ascii?

Tags: iproute

According to `ip-route(8)` :

> ip route save
>                 save routing table information to stdout
>                 This command behaves like ip route show except that the output is raw data suitable for passing to ip route restore.
>   
>   ip route restore
>                 restore routing table information from stdin
>                 This command expects to read a data stream as returned from ip route save.  It will attempt to restore the routing table information exactly as it
>                 was at the time of the save, so any translation of information in the stream (such as device indexes) must be done first. Any existing routes are
>                 left unchanged. Any routes specified in the data stream that already exist in the table will be ignored.

But when I use `ip route save > mydump` , It return binary unlike of manual page, Is it a bug? Or I use wrongly?

Comment: the `raw data` comment implies that the output might not be human readable. That seems to be correct in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dump your RT, Please consider, `ip route save` provide stdout and stderr, So you have to use :

```
ip route save 1> dump
```

If you don't use `1>` ip command, redirect stderr and stdout into dump.
NOTE: If you have a default gateway in your dump,  please add its network by hand such as :

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0
```

Then :

```
ip route restore < dump
```

But why with hand? Because first line of dump is dafualt gw and you get the following error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

Answer (score 3):

It is binary.  A definitive indicator of this is the fact that it won't allow you to dump the binary data to stdout, with a error message:

```
# ip route save
Not sending binary stream to stdout
Dump terminated
```

Comment: I answer completely,

Comment: @PersianGulf No you did not. You just specified an unnnecessary redirection. This one is the correct answer.

Comment: @Brian , But i tested.

Answer (score 2):

The format of `ip route save` is binary but, in case of Linux, it is identical to [rtnetlink(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/rtnetlink). There are many tools to read/write/manipulate this files, one of it is Python [pyroute2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyroute2).